# How do the StringBuffer insert() and deleteCharAt() methods work

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

In Java there is methods in either `StringBuffer()` or `StringBuilder()` called `insert()` and `deleteCharAt()` I am very interested in understanding a little more how these two specific methods work. Or how one would program one using the standard java String methods. I reckon they are pretty simple methods to write yourself?

Comment: Try looking at the source code of Respective classes.

Comment: Google `java grepcode stringbuilder`.

Comment: Or you could look inside the JDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Sun's implementation both methods are delegated to `StringBuffer`'s parent class `AbstractStringBuilder`:

```
public synchronized StringBuffer insert(int index, char str[], int offset,
                                        int len) 
{
    super.insert(index, str, offset, len);
    return this;
}

public synchronized StringBuffer deleteCharAt(int index) {
    super.deleteCharAt(index);
    return this;
}
```

`AbstractStringBuffer` has the following implementations:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder insert(int index, char str[], int offset,
                                    int len)
{
    if ((index < 0) || (index > length()))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    if ((offset < 0) || (len < 0) || (offset > str.length - len))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(
            "offset " + offset + ", len " + len + ", str.length " 
            + str.length);
    int newCount = count + len;
    if (newCount > value.length)
        expandCapacity(newCount);
    System.arraycopy(value, index, value, index + len, count - index);
    System.arraycopy(str, offset, value, index, len);
    count = newCount;
    return this;
}

public AbstractStringBuilder deleteCharAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);
    count--;
    return this;
}
```

So, nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

The `insert(…)` methods of both StringBuilder and StringBuffer use simple array copying implemented in `AbstractStringBuilder.insert(int, String)`:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder insert(int offset, String str) {
    if ((offset < 0) || (offset > length()))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    if (str == null)
        str = "null";
    int len = str.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    System.arraycopy(value, offset, value, offset + len, count - offset);
    str.getChars(value, offset);
    count += len;
    return this;
}
```

First it ensures that the internal `char []` array is large enough to store the result then moves the characters after the insertion point to the right using `System.arraycopy(…)` and overwrites characters starting at the insertion point with the given string.

Similarly, the `deleteCharAt(int)` methods of both StringBuilder and StringBuffer call `AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(int)`:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder deleteCharAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);
    count--;
    return this;
}
```

Deleting a character is done by using `System.arraycopy(…)` the other way around: this time the characters after the deletion point are shifted by one character to the left.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), both classes say the same thing about their methods. Insert inserts a string into a string based on the input. CharArray adds a string based on a CharArray and so on. DeleteCharAt removes a character at a certain part in the string.

StringBuffer is a little bit faster, but StringBuilder is newer. [2](http://kaioa.com/node/59)

The standard java String methods don't contain deleteCharAt() or insert() (that's why there is StringBuilder/Buffer), but you can probably find a way to work around it by substring().

Yes, you could write the methods yourself. I would look at the source for StringBuilder or StringBuilder in JDK.